# kettle Converting from other Databases to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, kettle, case-sensitive

I have a problem when I convert `mysql` database to `postgres`.

`mysql` tablenames and columns are all uppercase but `kettle` creates `postgres` tables all lowercase when i run this job. The components of tableoutput prints log just like this

> INSERT INTO USER_MENU ("FLOW_ID", "USER_ID" .... ,

I try mysql all lowercase, run successfully. I know postgres is case-sensitive but how to solve this case when `mysql` all uppercase or how to make the tableoutput to output lowercase sql.

Using kettle 6.1.0.1-R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick answer**: The create table statement is an editable text. In particular you can copy/paste it into a notepad (or any editor), change all to lowercase and copy/paste it back before to push the create button. (Useful also for non-standard SQL dialect, like Date/Time/Boolean types).

**Neat answer**: Edit the connection. On the right panel you have a `General/Advanced/Options/Pooling/Cluster` menu. Go to the `Advanced` panel. There you can tell weather your database is using uppercase or lowercase.

**Stupid but quick use of the clever answer**: Use the `Advanced` menu to force quote around identifiers.

**Really smart answer**: Edit the MySQL connection and select the `Options` menu, and refer to that [page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html). Postgres conforms strictly to standand SQL, so be reluctant to change the `Options` default for Postgres connections.

Comment: thanks, i use the Advanced menu to force quote around identifiers  and solve it